# Graphite divideSeries(#E,#A) return no data

Tags: grafana, graphite

I have 2 series(#A and #E), one contains how much x I gain each minute, and the other contains how much x I need.
My goal is to calculate how long time it'll take before I'm done.
I've tried to do `divideSeries(#A,#E)`, which returns "No data" on my graph.

#A:

`currentAbove(summarize(removeAboveValue(removeBelowValue(derivative(screeps.emil8250.ControllerProgress), 0), 2000), '30m', 'avg', false), 0)`

#E:

`currentAbove(diffSeries(#C, #D), 0)`

Currently #A is 108 and #E is 154.003, so I'd assume the result would be 1.425,95.

Any suggestions on why this isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this, by converting x to percent and then using derivative to find delta.
Then I used scale instead of divideSeries to calculate how many hours was left.